# Public Role permissions sometimes doesn't work

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I create with a action a new channel, i wanna deny the reading permission for the public role but it works only sometimes. Sometimes everybody can read it sometimes the permission is denied. Can anybody help me?

```
TextChannel channel = cat.createTextChannel(getFormatedName()  + "-ticket-" + User.getId())
                .addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.MESSAGE_READ))
                .addPermissionOverride(getAdminRole(), EnumSet.of(Permission.MESSAGE_READ), null)
                .addPermissionOverride(guild.getMemberById(User.getId()), EnumSet.of(Permission.MESSAGE_READ), null)
                .complete();
```

Comment: How do expect someone to help you without any code?

Comment: sry, i paste the code in the description

Comment: This is probably an issue with a collision between overrides added by the category and overrides added manually.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in versions older than **4.2.0_174**. I recommend you update to fix this issue.

#### Why does this happen?

When you create a channel in a category using Category#createTextChannel it will first apply all the permission overrides from that category. After this, you apply your manual overrides which might collide with the existing overrides from the category. Due to a bug this would end up with 2 overrides in the request. This causes inconsistent output that can cause strange results.

Comment: wow i changed my version in maven but now my ide cant import the jda

Comment: 4.2.0_174 doesnt work i update to 4.2.0_168, i hope it will work